# How to make a Chromium instance with its own icon

Tags: .desktop

As you probably have noticed most calendaring applications in Linux suck, so I have decided doing something about it.

Basically I want to create an Arch package that puts Google Calendar right into the applications menu. That launches Google calendar right away into Chromium, without the navigation bar, by the following command:

chromium --app=https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r

The question is that I wanted to make it in such way that it had its own icon. That when it's launched, in the task bar, it's associated with its own icon instead of the Chromium one.

I know this is possible because that was the exact behaviour of the Google Calendar app, till Google decided to deprecate apps in Chromium. Specifically the line was:

chromium --app-id=ejjicmeblgpmajnghnpcppodonldlgfn

Any idea about how this could be accomplished? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries

Comment: I'm sorry that page doesn't answer my question. This isn't about making a desktop entry, but more about separating instances of the same application.

When I launch my desktop entry it is managed from the same icon than any other opened Chromium window. I want to prevent that, that the app has its own separate icon in the task bar.

Comment: As I said on the Arch boards: create your own custom entry, point it at whatever icon you want and exec any command you want...

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this process](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-chrome-create-windows-10-app-website/) to create a shortcut into the desktop, and then move it into the folder "~/.local/share/applications"

Also I have suggested to include this [functionality](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=827845) directly into Chromium.